# Doctrine 2.2.2 - issue inserting multiple entries at once?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am unable to get this to work correctly.
It will insert entries twice and never set the project_id in project_data table, its always 0.
I have tried inserting multiple ways..

Like so

```
//... do some work
$project = new PSD_Model_Entity_Project();
$project->setStatusId($this->_em->find("PSD_Model_Entity_Status", '3'));
$project->addData('hello', $data->data->hello);

$this->_em->persist($project);
$this->_em->flush();
```

And Like so

```
$project = new PSD_Model_Entity_Project();
$project->setStatusId($this->_em->find("PSD_Model_Entity_Status", '3'));

$project_data = new PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data('hello', $data->data->hello,$project);

$this->_em->persist($project);
$this->_em->persist($project_data);
$this->_em->flush();
```

Doctrine Model:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PSD_Model_Entity_Project
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="project")
 */
class PSD_Model_Entity_Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer $project_id
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $project_id;

    /**
     * @var integer $dependent
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $dependent;

    /**
     * @var integer $iduser
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $iduser;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $modified
     * @Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $modified;

    /**
     * @var PSD_Model_Entity_Status
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PSD_Model_Entity_Status")
     * @JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="status_id")
     */
    private $status_id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data", mappedBy="project_id", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="name")
     */
    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function addData($name, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$name] = new PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data($name, $value, $this);
    }

    /**
     * Get project_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getProjectId()
    {
        return $this->project_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set dependent
     *
     * @param integer $dependent
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project
     */
    public function setDependent($dependent)
    {
        $this->dependent = $dependent;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dependent
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getDependent()
    {
        return $this->dependent;
    }

    /**
     * Set iduser
     *
     * @param integer $iduser
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project
     */
    public function setIduser($iduser)
    {
        $this->iduser = $iduser;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get iduser
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIduser()
    {
        return $this->iduser;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param datetime $created
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set modified
     *
     * @param datetime $modified
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project
     */
    public function setModified($modified)
    {
        $this->modified = $modified;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get modified
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getModified()
    {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    /**
     * Set status_id
     *
     * @param PSD_Model_Entity_Status $statusId
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project
     */
    public function setStatusId(\PSD_Model_Entity_Status $statusId = null)
    {
        $this->status_id = $statusId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status_id
     *
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Status 
     */
    public function getStatusId()
    {
        return $this->status_id;
    }
}

<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="project_data")
 */
class PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data
{
    /**
     * @var integer $project_data_id
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $project_data_id;

    /**
     * @var integer $project_id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PSD_Model_Entity_Project", inversedBy="data")
     */
    private $project_id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $value
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $value;


    public function __construct($name, $value, $project)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->project_id = $project;
    }

    /**
     * Set project_id
     *
     * @param PSD_Model_Entity_Project $projectId
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data
     */
    public function setProjectId(\PSD_Model_Entity_Project $projectId = null)
    {
        $this->project_id = $projectId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get project_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getProjectId()
    {
        return $this->project_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set value
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your data model properties should be marked as `protected` instead of `private`, according to the docs.

The reference to `$project_id` inside your `PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data` currently has this:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="integer")
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PSD_Model_Entity_Project", inversedBy="data")
 */
```

You could try changing the `Column` to `JoinColumn`:

```
/**
 * @JoinColumn()
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="PSD_Model_Entity_Project", inversedBy="data")
 */
```

Btw, I have a similar model and didn't need the `inversedBy`; but it's been a while since I have touched Doctrine so this may not make any difference whatsoever :)

Comment: i got it to work, i had to remove the @Column(type="integer") from project_id in PSD_Model_Entity_Project_Data.. But what about the multiple insert issue? it insert 2 entries every time. @Jack

Comment: @funkychicken818 have you tried setting `$data` to `protected` first? The docs don't recommend using `private` visibility.

Comment: @funkychicken818 updated my answer; if that doesn't help I'm out of tips :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Try setting the attributes, via the set, not with the constructor and see if this eliminates the duplicate row.